# How do I Concatenate or Combine the dictionary of same data to One

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary, django-views

I have the below set of 7 Dictionaries

```
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,1)':'Unmarked'}
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,2)':'Unmarked'}
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,3)':'Present'}
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,4)':'Unmarked'}
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,5)':'Unmarked'}
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,6)':'Absent'}
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,7)':'Unmarked'}
```

I want to convert into the below format.

```
{'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,1)':'Unmarked', 'date(2022,5,2)':'Unmarked', 'date(2022,5,3)':'Present', 'date(2022,5,4)':'Unmarked', 'date(2022,5,5)':'Unmarked', 'date(2022,5,6)':'Absent', 'date(2022,5,7)':'Unmarked'}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method:

```py
dcts = [
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,1)": "Unmarked"},
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,2)": "Unmarked"},
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,3)": "Present"},
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,4)": "Unmarked"},
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,5)": "Unmarked"},
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,6)": "Absent"},
    {"empid": 785, "empname": "Ibrahim", "date(2022,5,7)": "Unmarked"},
]

out = {k: v for d in dcts for k, v in d.items()}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "empid": 785,
    "empname": "Ibrahim",
    "date(2022,5,1)": "Unmarked",
    "date(2022,5,2)": "Unmarked",
    "date(2022,5,3)": "Present",
    "date(2022,5,4)": "Unmarked",
    "date(2022,5,5)": "Unmarked",
    "date(2022,5,6)": "Absent",
    "date(2022,5,7)": "Unmarked",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def Merge(a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
    res = a | b | c | d | e | f | g
    return res


a = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,1)':'Unmarked'}
b = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,2)':'Unmarked'}
c = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,3)':'present'}
d = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,4)':'Unmarked'}
e = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,5)':'Unmarked'}
f = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,6)':'Absent'}
g = {'empid':785, 'empname':'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,7)':'Unmarked'}

result = Merge(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce


lst = [{'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,1)': 'Unmarked'},
       {'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,2)': 'Unmarked'},
       {'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,3)': 'Present'},
       {'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,4)': 'Unmarked'},
       {'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,5)': 'Unmarked'},
       {'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,6)': 'Absent'},
       {'empid': 785, 'empname': 'Ibrahim', 'date(2022,5,7)': 'Unmarked'}]

def fun(dct1, dct2):
    res = dct1.copy()
    for key, value in dct2.items():
        if key not in dct1:
            res[key] = value
    return res

reduce(fun, lst)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).